# Resize in Windows Forms controls along with form resize

Tags: c#, winforms, size, height, width

I have a few controls (group boxes, tables, gridview, etc.) in my C# Windows Forms application, and I would like to scale them based on screen width/height.

For example, the screen starts at, let's say, 640x480 and then it gets maximized to 1920x1200.

I want to be able to increase the width/height of the controls so they look the exact same after the window gets re-sized.

What is the best way to do that, without setting every width/height property manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the best way to do that, without setting every width/height property manually?

Instead of specifying width and height, you can use the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties to have controls scale based on their containing elements.

Alternatively, you can use [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) to arrange your controls.

Comment: This makes sense, been playing around with it but my design is non-standard, the Dock only gives top, bottom and 3 center items. Can I make my custom dock somehow?

Comment: @sd_dracula You can't customize - you need to think in terms of the standard layout.  TableLayoutPanel might be an easier approach, if you're working with a "grid" style, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the control's `Anchor` property.

> As the name implies, this property forces the control to anchor itself
>   in a relative or absolute position within the parent form or control.
>   This property has four values that can be turned on or off:
>
> ```
> Top -- Indicates that the control should keep its top edge stationary in respect to the parent form (or control) top edge.
> Bottom -- Indicates that the control should keep its bottom edge stationary in respect to the parent form (or control) bottom edge.
> Left -- Indicates that the control should keep its left edge stationary in respect to the parent form (or control) left edge.
> Right -- Indicates that the control should keep its right edge stationary in respect to the parent form (or control) right edge.
> ```

IIRC, you want to select all the controls on the form using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and then setting the anchor property to top, bottom, left, and right.

Comment: That's fine to align them but I want them to expand their width/height depending on the new width/height of the form. Will that do it too?